# Does default language in play console's "main store listing" should be the one that supported by the BII?

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

If I implemented BIIs that only supports english, should my app's default language in Play Console's "main store listing" be in english too in order the app action to be approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Play store listing data has no effect on the way BIIs work with respect to the languages they support.  Your app should probably have one consistent name across languages, though, so it is always addressed the same way.